# how to animate grid view rows to display one row after another in a same page. And all should be on the page?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

how to animate grid view rows to display one row after another in a same page. And all should be on the page?
any body please help me out.thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Animating an `ASP.NET GridView` is not what you're after. You'll want to animate the HTML generated from the `ASP.NET GridView`, and for that you'll need `javascript` and/or `jQuery`. These scripting languages were built for the web and facilitate DOM manipulation.

In this case, a possible approach is to render the rows invisible on document ready, then display (and animate) them one at a time.

You should now have sufficient information to continue your search.

Answer (score 0):

after 2 days of my work i had done the following :

```
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">


        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("span[id$='label']").animate({marginLeft: "0.05in"},100).first().show("fast", function showNext() {
                $(this).next().show(200, showNext);
            });
});


    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="repeater1">
    <ItemTemplate>

   <asp:Label runat="server" ID="label" style="display:none" Text='<%#Eval("ename") %>'>
   </asp:Label>
   <br />
    </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```